# What factors limit the effiency of heat pumps to well below the Carnot efficiency?

Tags: thermodynamics, hvac

Aircon SEER values top out [around 23](https://jacobsheating.com/blog/seer-rating/). SEER is an anachronistic unit, but it can be converted into a *coefficient of performance* (COP) by multiplying by 0.293. This gives a value of around 6.7, which means that 1 kJ of electricity pumps 6.7 kJ of heat from the inside and deposits 7.7 kJ outside.

This sounds very good, but the most efficient possible is considerably higher. For a cool 22C (295K) indoor temperature vs a sweltering 40C (313K) day, the [Carnot limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_cycle) of COP is given by assuming entropy lost inside equals entropy gained outside: $T_C^{-1} \eta =T_H^{-1} (\eta+1)$, which gives $\eta = 16.4$. Thus the heat pumps are only *40% as efficient* as they could be for *liberal AC use on a very hot day*. Where do we lose so much efficiency?

**Motors:** They easily peak at [95%](https://www.aarohies.com/7-ways-to-improve-electric-motor-efficiency/) efficiency. AC is either 100% on or 100% off, so it presumably is designed to operate near this peak efficiency.

**Refrigerant compression/expansion:** Propellers and turbofans can be [about 80%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propulsive_efficiency) efficient, which can probably be pushed higher in a stationary setting without weight limits. Piston pumps hover around [85%](https://www.pumpsandsystems.com/reciprocating-pumps-vs-multi-stage-centrifugal-pumps).

**Forced convection:** It takes 2700 watts to move air around the vents in a medium size home according to [this HVAC source](https://bardi.com/how-many-watts-does-an-air-conditioner-use/) vs 10800 watts total. There is also energy used to pump the refrigerant through the pipes and run the noisy compressor fan. Thus over 33% of the power usage is just to move fluids (mainly air) around without expanding/compressing them, maybe a flat 30% in the most efficient systems which can afford wider piping?

**Finite temperature differences:** The transfer of heat to and from the refrigerant mandates that the refrigerant gets colder than indoor air and then hotter than the outdoor air. Maybe 5C on either side is a reasonable guess here for more efficient systems? That would make the Carnot limit for our 22C-40C case around 10, or 60% of the ideal case.

**Estimation of final efficiency:** $\eta/\eta_{Carnot} = (\eta_{motor} \eta_{compressor}  \eta_{deltaT}) (1 - P_{convect}/P_{compressor}) = 0.95*0.85*0.6*0.7 = 0.33$.

This is a bit below the 40% we calculated, but the 40% is a optimistic since it used a very wide indoor-outdoor delta-T value.

**Are these loss estimates reasonable?**

Comment: So, what efficiency losses does the Carnot efficiency include?

Comment: @SolarMike The Carnot efficiency does not include *any* losses. It is the efficiency in a perfect world where friction doesn't exist and ball bearings bounce forever. This question is about the real-life losses that make the performance below this theoretical maximum.

Comment: Good. So from there what other losses have you not included? Think about all the components in a real system.

Comment: @SolarMike: Presumably I covered most of the losses? Hopefully the answer will have a more complete list with quantitatively precise numbers (such as the actual refrigerant temperatures, etc).

Comment: So pipe losses? I commented in the hope that you would examine the problem more thoroughly yourself as part of a learning process.

Comment: @SolarMike: Are these significant compared to the energy needed to pump air out of the vents and past the compressor? I don't know the relevant parameters (pipe diameter, flow rate, etc). Maybe an HVAC engineer will have a better idea.

Comment: Duct losses <> pipe losses.

Comment: Motors might be 90% efficienct, but 100% of the power used is a loss in this system.  Everything that uses electricity is a loss.  Your theoretical number is for a system that uses zero electricity.